# How to group elements of vectors?

Tags: r, list, vector

I am not sure if I  will deliver the idea  of this question  clearly or no 
So, please accept my apologies.

I have a list x with six vectors.

```
 x <- list( c(2,3,4,6) , c(2,4,5), 
               c(1:5) ,c(1,2,5,6),c(3,5,6),c(1,4,5,6))
x
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 6

[[2]]
[1] 2 4 5

[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 5 6

[[5]]
[1] 3 5 6

[[6]]
[1] 1 4 5 6
```

I want to group the  elements of vectors  again  based on the idea below:

For each vector, I will check if the elements belong to other vectors in list or no, **for example**

From  the first vector:

```
[[1]]
[1] 2 3 4 6
```

I  want to check if the first element (2) belongs to third vector, fourth vector, and sixth vector or no.

```
[[3]]
[1] 1 2 3 4 5

[[4]]
[1] 1 2 5 6


[[6]]
[1] 1 4 5 6
```

Then if the second element(3) belongs to fourth and sixth vectors.

```
[[4]]
[1] 1 2 5 6

[[6]]
[1] 1 4 5 6
```

After that, if  the element(4) belongs to sixth vector or no

The result should be :

```
[1] 2 3 4
[1] 4 6
```

The similar procedure will be applied to the other vectors.

Comment: As far as I understand you want do check in which other list elements a element of the vector exists. That far I can follow you, but I can't find out how you build your result? Could you elaborate this point?

Comment: The result will be  a vector contains the element with the vectors number 
 We have a vector (2, 3,4,6) first value will be taken as element while the rest will be the vectors number,3 means (third vector),4 (fourth vector), and 6 (sixth vectors). 
 as you can see:  element 2  belongs to third and fourth vector, so I  put them together as one group (2 ,3 ,4), element   3 did not belong  to  fourth and sixth vectors, element  4 belongs to the sixth vector, so  4 with 6  in one group  (4 , 6), I hope it is clear now.

Comment: How can this be a simple atomic vector? In my mind this would be a nested list, with the first level the list elements from the "input" list, the second level each vector element and then the third level where to find them. Is that what you want?